# android: app widget:: How to pass non-persistent data to service from widget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

After lots of efforts in doing this, i finally asking. I have widget with textview, button and imageview. both views are loaded from preference. I am able to start myActivityA when user clicks textview and myActivityB when user clicks imageview from widget. But not able to receive onclick event (in service) for button. I am doing this in following manner.

MyWidgetProvider class

```
final ComponentName serviceName = new ComponentName(context, "com.mypkg.MyService");
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_main);
Intent intent = new Intent(Service.TOGGLE_ACTION);
intent.setComponent(serviceName);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context,0 /* no requestCode */, intent, 0 /* no flags */);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button1, pendingIntent);
```

In MyService class,

```
// broadcast message receiver for commands to service.
private BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    String action = intent.getAction();
            String cmd = intent.getStringExtra("Command");

            if (TOGGLE_ACTION.equals(action)) 
            {
                m_iKey = intent.getIntExtra("MyService.MyKey", 0);

    // call functions defined in MyService.

            }
}
};
```

My problem is i am not able to receive `TOGGLE_ACTION` in service at all. `OnStartCommand` is called in MyService,

Can any one suggest what could be issue?

What exactly i want from button click event is....
If service is not started (service is started in first activity, life span is now limited to activity) then start it... and `TOGGLE_ACTION` should be executed.
IF service is already started(means my activity is minimized) then `TOGGLE_ACTION` should be executed.

Is there any other way to achieve this?
Or other way to pass some data and call some routine of service from widget?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Intent intent= new Intent(context, myActivityB.class);
PendingIntent pending=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 , intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pending);
```

R.id.button this is your button Id.

Comment: Thanks Jeeva, on button click event i dont want to start activity. I want to execute or intimate routine defined in Service.